# How to get multiple responses to a single ajax request in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a web app, where I want to provide a search function. I am sending the searched name with an ajax request, and i want to pull the records of that particular person. But since there are many details that are to be displayed, I am finding it difficult to get the response. (I am not able to get more than one response at a time)

I want to know, if there is a way to get multiple responses for a single request, or a way to send all my variables in the target PHP file to the requesting javascript file as an array or something.

Thank you. If this question is asked before, please provide the link.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you're getting the responses currently with some relevant code from your HTML, PHP and JS?

Comment: You can respond with a `json` array containing all the data you want

Comment: Check this link it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171583/ajax-example-with-json-response-with-object-being-passed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **JSON** as the datatype to communicate between **PHP**(Backend) and **Javascript**(Frontend). Example:

### PHP

```
<? 
$person = array("name"=>"Jon Skeet","Reputation"=>"Infinitely Increasing");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($person);
?>
```

### Javascript/jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_script.php",
  dataType: "JSON"

}).success(function(person) {
  alert(person.name) //alerts Jon Skeet
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Add everything you want to an array, then call `json_encode` on it.

```
$data = array();

$data[] = $person1;

$data[] = $person2;

echo json_encode($data);
```